# I can't create the setup in .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, setup-project

good afternoon!

I'm trying to create a setup in .NET and it's showing an error when compiling the code.

> WARNING: The value of the "PublicKey" attribute in "Microsoft .NET
> Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)" does not match that in the file
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce
> Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX472\NDP472
> -KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe".

[image: Error image]

I tried to install the requested file again and was unsuccessful.

Comment: First warning says you are missing the VBE Interop. See https://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=microsoft.vbe.interop.dll&arch=32bit&version=10.0.4504.0

Comment: Even placing the interop dll, the .NET Framework error appears

Comment: Did you fix the interop error (Office and VBE)?  Did you do a clean build?  Error may be due to intermediate obj files containing wrong versions of dlls.  Clean build may resolve issue.  The version number is in the csproj file.  What you may need to also do is from Solution Explorer delete the libraries that are giving the error.  Then read add reference.  This will update the version in the csproj file to match the version of dll installed on your machine.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.3#1734--visual-studio-2022-version-1734

Comment: I checked with a friend compiling the same project and created the folder normally. I believe the error is the one reported for the same version... I will update my version

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant provided the link. This issue is mentioned in the [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.3#1734--visual-studio-2022-version-1734).

[image]

You only need to update Visual Studio 2022 to a version after 17.3.5

Comment: Good morning

I made the corrections to the Exel Dll as proposed. Very strange that it still doesn't generate the Framework folder to install alongside the software in setup. I will test the Visual Studio update and I verified that mine is on 16.9.

Comment: I checked with a friend compiling the same project and created the folder normally. I believe the error is the one reported for the same version... I will update my version

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: @Luiz If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.